# Почему system не работает?

Tags: c#

Написал я вот такой простенький код,всё подключил и скачал,но после запуска терминал выдает ошибку:

> E:\coding\obj\Debug\net7.0.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(4,12): error CS0579: Повторяющийся атрибут "global::System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttr
> ibute" [E:\coding\coding.csproj].

Да и слово `System` не подсвечивалось,будто сама прога его не задействовала. Понимаю,что вопрос примитивный,но всё же помогите пожалуйста). Заранее спасибо! Если что,то я пишу в vs code

```cs
using System;

namespace coding {

    class Program {

        static void Main() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

содержимое .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>CODING</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(ExcludeRestorePackageImports)' != 'true' ">
    <RestoreSuccess Condition=" '$(RestoreSuccess)' == '' ">True</RestoreSuccess>
    <RestoreTool Condition=" '$(RestoreTool)' == '' ">NuGet</RestoreTool>
    <ProjectAssetsFile Condition=" '$(ProjectAssetsFile)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)project.assets.json</ProjectAssetsFile>
    <NuGetPackageRoot Condition=" '$(NuGetPackageRoot)' == '' ">$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\</NuGetPackageRoot>
    <NuGetPackageFolders Condition=" '$(NuGetPackageFolders)' == '' ">C:\Users\Legion\.nuget\packages\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages</NuGetPackageFolders>
    <NuGetProjectStyle Condition=" '$(NuGetProjectStyle)' == '' ">PackageReference</NuGetProjectStyle>
    <NuGetToolVersion Condition=" '$(NuGetToolVersion)' == '' ">6.5.0</NuGetToolVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(ExcludeRestorePackageImports)' != 'true' ">
    <SourceRoot Include="C:\Users\Legion\.nuget\packages\" />
    <SourceRoot Include="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

{
  "format": 1,
  "restore": {
    "E:\\CODING\\CODING.csproj": {}
  },
  "projects": {
    "E:\\CODING\\CODING.csproj": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "restore": {
        "projectUniqueName": "E:\\CODING\\CODING.csproj",
        "projectName": "CODING",
        "projectPath": "E:\\CODING\\CODING.csproj",
        "packagesPath": "C:\\Users\\Legion\\.nuget\\packages\\",
        "outputPath": "E:\\CODING\\obj\\",
        "projectStyle": "PackageReference",
        "fallbackFolders": [
          "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\NuGetPackages"
        ],
        "configFilePaths": [
          "C:\\Users\\Legion\\AppData\\Roaming\\NuGet\\NuGet.Config",
          "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.FallbackLocation.config",
          "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config"
        ],
        "originalTargetFrameworks": [
          "net7.0"
        ],
        "sources": {
          "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\NuGetPackages\\": {},
          "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\library-packs": {},
          "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": {}
        },
        "frameworks": {
          "net7.0": {
            "targetAlias": "net7.0",
            "projectReferences": {}
          }
        },
        "warningProperties": {
          "warnAsError": [
            "NU1605"
          ]
        }
      },
      "frameworks": {
        "net7.0": {
          "targetAlias": "net7.0",
          "imports": [
            "net461",
            "net462",
            "net47",
            "net471",
            "net472",
            "net48",
            "net481"
          ],
          "assetTargetFallback": true,
          "warn": true,
          "frameworkReferences": {
            "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
              "privateAssets": "all"
            }
          },
          "runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\7.0.200\\RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ну удалите его. Вроде оно по умолчанию импортировано, но это не точно

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.52.php

Comment: Странно, у меня такой код запустился... И с `using System;`, и без него.

Comment: @nchistov это не странно, потому что ошибка не в представленном коде

Comment: Открой файл `.csproj` в виде текста, и посмотри там указанный атрибут TargetFramework

Comment: @Grundy я открыл и там было вот это   <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>.Что мне дальше с этим делать ?

Comment: Добавь содержимое `.csproj` в вопрос

Comment: @Grundy добавил

Comment: Это точно весь код, который есть?

Comment: @Grundy,пошарившись в иерархии я нашел ещё пару папок,где в названии было .csproj,больше нет

Comment: `E:\coding\coding.csproj` - вот этот файл - первый? Он точно сохранен и в нем нет двух TargetFramework? Попробуй закрыть его и заново проект открыть

Comment: Лучше заново проект создать